# send array to frescojs pro show api

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

Im using frescojs pro to view my images in a sexy box (:

It works very well.

Now i need to get the images from an PHP Array, but i dont know how to send it to the frescojs API.

My Array is prepared and looks like this

```
array(5) 
{
  [0]=>
  string(62) "http://www.sample.com/wp-content/uploads/bunds_cd_4.jpg"
  [1]=>
  string(62) "http://www.sample.com/wp-content/uploads/bunds_cd_2.jpg"
  [2]=>
  string(62) "http://www.sample.com/wp-content/uploads/bunds_cd_1.jpg"
  [3]=>
  string(62) "http://www.sample.com/wp-content/uploads/bunds_cd_3.jpg"
  [4]=>
  string(62) "http://www.sample.com/wp-content/uploads/bunds_cd_5.jpg"
}
```

how can i put this array in the frescojs show field?

On the DOC-Page of this script it is shown so:
http://www.frescojs.com/documentation/api

```
// use urls
Fresco.show(['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg']);

// or objects
Fresco.show([
  { url: 'image1.jpg', caption: 'Caption for this image' },
  { url: 'image2.jpg', caption: 'Another caption' }
]);
```

What i need for? is it called JSON?

greet;s satinez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to json_encode that php array and store it into an var then you can pass that var to js something like that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php $php_array = array("abc","def","ghi");
$js_array = json_encode($php_array);
echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n"; ?>
</script>
```